# SwiftUI state change is not reflected in view's body

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider the following SwiftUI code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum CurrentContentView {
  case translate, settings
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var currentView: CurrentContentView = .translate
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      
      TopView(currentView: $currentView)
      ZStack {
        TranslateView()
          .opacity(currentView == .translate ? 1 : 0)
          .disabled(currentView == .settings)
          .allowsHitTesting(currentView == .translate)
        SettingsView()
          .opacity(currentView == .settings ? 1 : 0)
          .disabled(currentView == .translate)
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
  
  func goToSettings() {
    currentView = .settings
  }
}
```

Upon calling the `goToSettings()` function from another class, the change of `currentView` is not reflected in `ContentView`'s body. Which I don't understand; the @State property wrapper should ensure that a view is updated when the variable changes, right?

Comment: Sorry @Phobos - I should have mentioned more explicitly that the `goToSettings` function does not work. What I try to do in that function, is change the state variable `currentView`, i.e. the body of `ContentView` should update accordingly.

Comment: You can’t call functions in a SwiftUI view from another class. SwiftUI views should not be held in variables. There is an underlying storage that is inaccessible from the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by using the `@ObservableObject` property wrapper:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum CurrentContentView {
  case translate
  case settings
}

class ContentViewState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var currentView: CurrentContentView = .translate
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var contentViewState = ContentViewState()
  
  @AppStorage("translationProvider") private var translationProvider: TranslationProvider = .google
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      TopView(contentViewState: contentViewState)
      ZStack {
        TranslateView()
          .opacity(contentViewState.currentView == .translate ? 1 : 0)
          .disabled(contentViewState.currentView == .settings)
          .allowsHitTesting(contentViewState.currentView == .translate)
        SettingsView()
          .opacity(contentViewState.currentView == .settings ? 1 : 0)
          .disabled(contentViewState.currentView == .translate)
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
  
  func goToSettings() {
    contentViewState.currentView = .settings
  }
}
```

My solution is based on [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects).

Comment: You should look at the article more closely you are misusing ObservedObject

Comment: It should be `@StateObject ` instead of `ObservedObject` right? Edited the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, ObservedObject doesn’t have the ability to maintain lifecycle. It shouldn’t be used to initialize, it is for passing around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this harder than it needs to be. If you have a state value and you're passing a binding to that to `TopView`, then just set the binding value in `TopView` to your new setting. You haven't included the code in `TopView` so it's hard to tell when you are calling that `goToSettings()` function, but as others have said, you can't pass instances of SwiftUI views around (well, you *can*, but it won't work like you think it will). View instances are frequently created and re-created, that is why there are storage wrappers like `@State`.

In addition to that, view builders can handle conditional content, so there is no need for the `ZStack` and all of the conditional opacity stuff. You can implement it like this:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    TopView(currentView: $currentView)
    switch currentView {
    case .translate: 
        TranslateView()
    case .settings:
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

`TopView` should be doing something like:

```swift
@Binding var currentView: CurrentContentView

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button("Translate") { currentView = .translate }
        Button("Settings") { currentView = .settings }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jrturton, I am aware that this is a possibility, but the caveat here is that `TranslateView()` contains a `WebView`, and any input in the `WebView` element will be erased when `currentView` is changed (i.e. a re-render reloads the webpage reloads).